# update conditionally base on maximum of a column in a special group hql

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, hql

I want to update  column c5 (to 1) of each grouped date base on column c1,c2,c3 where c3 is maximum in same c1,c2 group.I am working with hql on oracle db

```
c1    |  c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 | c5 after update
2000  |   a | 01 | x  | 0  | 0
2000  |   a | 01 | y  | 0  | 0
2000  |   a | 01 | z  | 0  | 0
2000  |   a | 02 | z  | 0  | 1
2000  |   a | 02 | x  | 0  | 1
...........................
2000  |   b | 01 | x  | 0  | 0
2000  |   b | 01 | y  | 0  | 0
2000  |   b | 01 | z  | 0  | 0
2000  |   b | 02 | z  | 0  | 1
..........................
..........................
2001  |   a | 01 | x  | 0  | 0
2001  |   a | 01 | y  | 0  | 0
2001  |   a | 01 | z  | 0  | 0
2001  |   a | 02 | z  | 0  | 0
2001  |   a | 02 | x  | 0  | 0
2001  |   a | 02 | y  | 0  | 0
2001  |   a | 02 | w  | 0  | 0
2001  |   a | 03 | y  | 0  | 1
2001  |   a | 03 | w  | 0  | 1
...........................
2001  |   b | 01 | x  | 0  | 0
2001  |   b | 01 | y  | 0  | 0
2001  |   b | 02 | x  | 0  | 1
2001  |   b | 02 | z  | 0  | 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with hql, but a quick Google search shows it's "similar" to SQL but it is object oriented. In your problem, you must update a standard, relational Oracle table, so it's not clear why you need or want to use hql.

If you have access to the Oracle database in a way that can use simple SQL statements, you can execute the update with the MERGE statement, like this: (assuming `td` is the name of your table)

```
merge into td
  using ( select   c1, c2, max(c3) as max_c3
          from     td
          group by c1, c2
        ) x
        on (td.c1 = x.c1 and td.c2 = x.c2 and td.c3 = max_c3)
when matched then update
  set c5 = 1
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use windows aggregate function `max` partitioning it by column `c1`, `c2` in`case` as below to generate your desired result.

```
SELECT t2.c1,
       t2.c2,
       t2.c3,
       t2.c4,
       CASE
           WHEN t2.c3 = max(t2.c3) over(partition BY t2.c1, t2.c2
                                        ORDER BY t2.c1) THEN 1
           ELSE 0
       END AS c5
FROM table1 t2
ORDER BY t2.c1,
         t2.c2,
         t2.c3
```

**Result**

```
C1      C2  C3  C4   C5
-----------------------
2000    a   1   x    0
2000    a   1   y    0
2000    a   1   z    0
2000    a   2   z    1
2000    a   2   x    1
2000    b   1   x    0
2000    b   1   y    0
2000    b   1   z    0
2000    b   2   z    1
2001    a   1   x    0
2001    a   1   y    0
2001    a   1   z    0
2001    a   2   x    0
2001    a   2   y    0
2001    a   2   z    0
2001    a   2   w    0
2001    a   3   w    1
2001    a   3   y    1
2001    b   1   x    0
2001    b   1   y    0
2001    b   2   z    1
2001    b   2   x    1
```

You can check the demo **[here](http://rextester.com/TSY56273)**

Hope this will help.

Comment: thank you so much.I want hql but I think I can not write it with hql and have to use sql as you answered me...but may you edit  your answer to update c5 to specific number(0 or 1)? (I don't want to select...I want to update)

Comment: Oh. i missed the update part. As its already written by mathguy above, so you can check that. it will work for you, however you need to set column `c5` to `default 0` in ddl.

Comment: so I can't using your query(with some modification ) to update ?

Comment: how abou this? update table1 t3 set t3.c5 = (select CASE WHEN t2.c3 = max(t2.c3) over(partition BY t2.c1, t2.c2  ORDER BY t2.c1) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END AS c6 FROM table1 t2 ORDER BY t2.c1,t2.c2,
         t2.c3)

Comment: @faraa: the query you pasted will not work. merge will work perfect as per your requirement.